# Change the Color Of Certain Words In Textarea using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, colors

How to Change the Color Of Certain Words In Textarea using Jquery ?

For instance, i have a textarea `<textarea id="txt">        </textarea>`

When i type into the textarea, certain words like "is, a , was ..." should be colored or highlighted.

The aim is to create a ultra simple HTML syntax highlighter for my project that's all !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is completely impossible.

You need to use a content-editable `<iframe>`.

The reason it's not possible is that the `<TEXTAREA>` has no ability, in any browser, to support formatting. You need a differnt kind of element, so that words can be wrapped in  elements, formatting the text.

Comment: Edited answer to explain *why* it's not possible.

Comment: They use ContentEditable elements, not `<textarea>`s.

Comment: @Aakash: Have a look at the sources of [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) at http://github.com/remy/jsbin and see what it uses for coloring the HTML.

Comment: You can try this plugin: [link]http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/[/link]

I haven't had the chance to use it yet, but looks simple. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can color the text in a Textarea, NobleCount provides the possibility to change via css the font color in a Textarea right after maxlength, using jQuery, [see here at example num. test7](http://theproductguy.com/noblecount/noblecount.demo.html). Now all we have to figure out is how to only color certains sections, or how to color by starting and-or ending at a defined charactor count.