# Change color of TextArea words

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

Is there a way to change the color of certain words in a TextArea?  For example,

"There are three possums in the road."

I would like to color 'possums' red.

Comment: I think, I have provided better and really working solution - [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) provides realtime coloring during typing into editable area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qooxdoo does use a native TextArea so it depends on the native TextAreas capabilities. As TextAreas do not support that feature, we can't do much about it.

See also answers on the following questions for further information:

[Change the Color Of Certain Words In Textarea using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990157/change-the-color-of-certain-words-in-textarea-using-jquery)

[Multicolor Text Highlighting in a Textarea or Text Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845813/multicolor-text-highlighting-in-a-textarea-or-text-input)

Answer (score 1):

In textarea you can't. But there is posibility of "editable div". See http://codemirror.net/ (primarily for code listing but you can also extend it with a custom parser)