# How to colorate the repeated words using a <p> Tag?

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone I am writing a script to color the words that appear repeated in my text area in order to achieve it I tried obtaining the list of this wods, my textarea looks like this:

```
<textarea cols="150" rows="15" id="texto">"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX8.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
</textarea>
```

I already tried obtaining a list of the words that appears repeated in the text area, I stored it in an array called: colorWords, I want to find a way to print in the screen my text area with this particularly words colored, the idea is using

Tags rather than modify directly my textarea.

```
var colorWords = Object.keys(filtered)
```

In order to be more clear the words that I want to color are all the words contained in my colorWords list.
The problem is that I don´t know how to achieve this, I would like to appreciate any suggestions to do this task.
My desired output is to print the same textarea with this particularly words colored into a

Tag area, not in the textarea since it is not possible.

My complete code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><script src="./code33_files/lodash.js"></script> 
</head><body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<textarea cols="150" rows="15" id="texto">"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX8.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
</textarea>
<script>
var splitWords = document.getElementById("texto").value.split(/[["\|~]/);
var removeArray  = _.remove(splitWords, function (word) {return word !== '' && word !== ' ' && word !== '\n'});
console.log(removeArray);
var dict = removeArray.reduce(function(p,c) {
    if (p[c] === undefined) {
        p[c] = 1;
    } else {
        p[c]++;
    }
    return p;
},{});

var filtered = Object.keys(dict).reduce(function (filtered, key) {
    if (dict[key] > 1) filtered[key] = dict[key];
    return filtered;
}, {});

var colorWords = Object.keys(filtered)
console.log(filtered)
console.log(colorWords)
</script>



</body></html>
```

Comment: You cannot style individual words/letters inside a textarea. If you are looking to make a wysiwyg/rich text editor then you will need to either build your own or use one of the many available packages out there.

Comment: You need `WYSIWYG editor` to serve your purpose

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821110/change-color-of-textarea-words

Comment: Thanks @ShekharPankaj , I understand the situation, I will try using WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Since I cant not achieve the thing that I want, I will modify my original question.